# delayed_job restart would restart all processes correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

So, when I start DJ, I do it like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production ./script/delayed_job --pool=user,op,fb:2 --pool=mail,intercom,low,default:2 start
```

My question is this: when I restart it, do I need to specify same parameters? That is, would the following command be enough?

```
RAILS_ENV=production ./script/delayed_job restart
```

Or do I stop it, and give the start command again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer it myself, yes. DJ will restart the current processes properly, all in their own place.

```
2016-05-31T06:25:59+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:699)] Exiting...
2016-05-31T06:26:03+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:709)] Exiting...
2016-05-31T06:26:05+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:716)] Exiting...
2016-05-31T06:26:10+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:723)] Exiting...
2016-05-31T06:26:16+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:29890)] Starting job worker
2016-05-31T06:26:16+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:29897)] Starting job worker
2016-05-31T06:26:16+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:29915)] Starting job worker
2016-05-31T06:26:16+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:*** pid:29907)] Starting job worker
```

Something like that.